# What does information in square brackets after a file path mean in RSpec?

Tags: rspec, rspec3

The documentation for RSpec mentions the [--bisect option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/command-line/bisect) , which when run provides a minimal reproduction, such as

```
rspec ./spec/calculator_10_spec.rb[1:1] ./spec/calculator_1_spec.rb[1:1] --seed 1234
```

What does the `[1:1]` bit mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `rspec --help`:

> **** Filtering/tags ****
>
> In addition to the following options for selecting specific files, groups, or
>       examples, you can select individual examples by appending the line number(s) to
>       the filename:
>
> ```
> rspec path/to/a_spec.rb:37:87
> ```
>
> You can also pass example ids enclosed in square brackets:
>
> ```
> rspec path/to/a_spec.rb[1:5,1:6]
> # run the 5th and 6th examples/groups defined in the 1st group
> ```

It's mentioned in the release notes of [RSpec 3.3](http://rspec.info/blog/2015/06/rspec-3-3-has-been-released/):

> RSpec 3.3 introduces a new way to identify examples and example
>   groups: unique IDs. The IDs are scoped to a particular file and are
>   based on the index of the example or group. For example, this command:
>
> ```
> $ rspec spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb[1:2,1:4]
> ```
>
> …would run the 2nd and 4th
>   example or group defined under the 1st top-level group defined in
>   spec/unit/baseball_spec.rb.